# numeric comparison giving wrong result (javascript)

Tags: javascript

The following code is giving false result all the time. I think i am comparing two numeric variables. is that not so?

```
var request; var getfilesize; var maxdisplaysize=2097152;
    request = $.ajax({
    type: "HEAD",
    url: getfile,
    success: function () {
      getfilesize = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Length");
      console.log("Size is" + getfilesize+'xxx');
    }
    });
    parseInt( getfilesize, 10 );
if ( getfilesize < maxdisplaysize ) {
    $("#displayfile").load(getfile);
    console.log('file size less then 2mb 2097152bytes');
} else {
    $("#displayfile").append('<p>sorry large file<p>');
}
```

Pl advice why the if condition is always evaluating to be false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to `parseInt()` has no effect, as you don't do anything with the result.

```
getfilesize = parseInt(getfilesize, 10);
```

is what you want. The `parseInt()` function does not (and **cannot**) modify the first parameter.

Now, that said, the next problem you're going to want to deal with is the fact that your ajax call is **asynchronous**.  You need to put that code that uses the file size **inside** the "success" callback.

Comment: main issue was the async call, putting it inside the async call fixed everything. i do not need to convert now. thx for pointing that!!!